# download an xlsx file with sorted column in Java with XSSF

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sorting, xssf

In my app, users can download an xlsx but now i want to sort this file by alphabetic order for the column 'Supplier' AND by Ascending date for the column 'ETD'.

I have a method to create my xlsx file :

```
public XSSFWorkbook createCalendarExcelFile(final List<CalendarDTO> calendars, final User user) {
        final XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DD_MM_YYYY);
        final XSSFCellStyle borderStyle = ExcelUtils.createBorderStyle(workbook, BORDER_THIN);
        final XSSFFont boldFont = ExcelUtils.createFontStyle(workbook, BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        final XSSFFont normalFont = ExcelUtils.createFontStyle(workbook, BOLDWEIGHT_NORMAL);
        final XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
        final XSSFRow headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);

        int headerIndex = 0;

        //Header
        this.createTabColumn(headerRow, headerIndex++, ORDER_TYPE, boldFont, borderStyle);
        this.createTabColumn(headerRow, headerIndex++, ORDER_SUBTYPE, boldFont, borderStyle);
        this.createTabColumn(headerRow, headerIndex++, FILE, boldFont, borderStyle);
        this.createTabColumn(headerRow, headerIndex++, SUPPLIER_ID + SPACE + HYPHEN + SPACE + NAME, boldFont, borderStyle);
        if (CoAndGoConstants.BU_PROFILE.equals(user.getRole().getProfile().getName())) {
            this.createTabColumn(headerRow, headerIndex++, DEADLINE, boldFont, borderStyle);
        } else {
            this.createTabColumn(headerRow, headerIndex++, FIRST_DEADLINE, boldFont, borderStyle);
            this.createTabColumn(headerRow, headerIndex++, FINAL_DEADLINE, boldFont, borderStyle);
        }
        this.createTabColumn(headerRow, headerIndex++, DELAY_REASON, boldFont, borderStyle);
        this.createTabColumn(headerRow, headerIndex++, ETD, boldFont, borderStyle);
```

etc etc, and i fill it with some streams and loop. (More than 200 rows, so i can not paste everything here) and everything works as i wanted.

But now i could not find a way to parameter the "auto-sort" by alphabetic order for the column 'Supplier' and Ascending date for the column 'ETD' before the download by users.

it's better if i do not use an external library.

Ty.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the sorted data from database using ORDER BY

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).